# Sitecore: Login Page For End User

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

I am need of some help.

1) I want to create a login page for my end users. I need them to be able to create an account and save the account to my SQL database, not into sitecore instance. Then when they login to the site, I need that account to pass a user ID from the database into sitecore.

2) Once the user ID is passed into sitecore, I need sitecore to display a unique page depending on the users choice of widgets that they create. So after they create an account I need the first display page to be a design page. Where it looks like the experience editor and they can drag and drop widgets from a set list.

Is this something possible to do? I have a bunch of end users, so I dont want to flood my sitecore instance with all the accounts. I want to have them stored in a separate database table. Also, is it possible to create an experience editor experience for the end users to use? Those are my two big questions.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution summary

You probably want to look at using a centralized identity management system, something like Active Directory, or similar. Then, you can use Federated Authentication with that system to delegate the authentication to the external system. In this model, you check for authentication (or provide a login screen) and redirect users over to the authentication system. When they return, you consume the response from the authentication system and log them into Sitecore using the API.

This achieves your desire to have your users stored in an external system, and you won't have to build up an authentication storage system yourself.

Once authenticated, these users can either be virtual (not in the Sitecore DB) or persistent (created in the Core DB). In your scenario, it sounds like you would like to use virtual users.

## Resources

With Sitecore 9, you can configure federated authentication using OWIN middleware: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/federated_authentication/using_federated_authentication_with_sitecore

Your tags, however, imply that you are on Sitecore 8. This blog has a guide on how to achieve this with older versions: 
http://blog.baslijten.com/how-to-add-federated-authentication-with-sitecore-and-owin/

Comment: Thanks for this information. I actually plan on using SSO authentication. Is it possible to do that same process with SSO rather than Federated? This is my first time playing around with logins, so I am not to familiar with the things that work and don't work. Much Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify? FedAuth is a form of SSO. Do you have details on the particular SSO pattern you wish to implement? In any case, yes, you can implement any form of SSO pattern, it is just about how much effort you wish to go to.